# Using geometry with scrbook offsets page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, geometry, scrbook

I am trying to create a template for a bachelor thesis using scrbook right now. The university demands that the documents margins are as follow:

left = 50mm
right = 20mm
top = 20mm
bottom = 20mm

When using geometry I get the correct margins however the pagenumber indicated at the top is no longer centered but offset by the left margin.

I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{\pagemark}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{\geometry{rmargin=20mm,lmargin=50mm}}
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal self contained example that shows your problem. Then others can test your code in their system and see if they get the same problem.

Comment: Edited the post. Sorry

Comment: If you want to center the \chead relative to the page, not the type area, you could add the desired amount of horizontal space to the right or left of the pagemark: `\cohead{\pagemark\hspace*{30mm}}` (for odd pages)
`\cehead{\hspace*{30mm}\pagemark}` (for even pages) is a cheap workaround, but it works for me in the MWE.

Comment: This works in the example i provided. However when used with Chapters and a ToC this does not seem to work whenever the page starts with a new chapter or when listing the ToC.

Comment: My bad. I used the non-starred version (`\cohead{}` etc.), but it should have been `\cohead*{}` (just as you used `\chead*{}` in the OP). The starred command sets the same header content for both syles, "scrheadings" and the (usually simpler) "plain.scrheadings". The latter is used (by default) in the first page of the ToC or of a chapter. Try `\cohead*{\pagemark\hspace{30mm}}` (no star required with `\hspace`) and see what happens.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly thanks!